# $151$ seats for $3$ parties - How to fill them in a way that no party gets absolute majority?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation

I've tried to answer the following problem:

> [image]

In my mind, I thought about a very complicated solution: First counting $i=j\geq k$ divided in various cases and then taking appropriate permutations $k=j\geq i$, etc. But the solution in the book is:

> [image]

- It is so simple that I don't know what is happening in there, I don't know how he came up with $\sum_{i=1}^{75} i$?
- I am also confused about the given conditions: How did he came up with them and how is he actually using it?

Comment: Personally, I would have found the number of solutions to the equation $i + j + k = 151$ in the nonnegative integers, then subtracted the number of solutions in which one of the variables exceeded $75$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's obtain the conditions.

Clearly $i,j,k\le 75$. 
$$k=151-i-j\le 75$$ Then $i+j\ge 76$ and therefore $76-i \le j \le 75$.

The author then looks at each possibility for $i$. For each one, the number of possibilities for $j$ is 
$$75-(76-i)+1=i.$$

The answer is therefore the sum $$1+2+...+75=2850.$$